# Same module under two different Application menus in ServiceNow (Same APP/Instance)

Tags: javascript, module, servicenow

I've got a module in ServiceNow that some users can see under their specific Application Menu, at the same time some other users cannot see it under their own Application menu.

So the question is , How can I enable this module to be placed under BOTH these Application Menus?

Roles looks OK (the way i want it) but since I got "Order" field with a value this module only shows at one place.

Answer (score 0):

To make the module appear under the second application menu , you have to add it to the modules list for that application.
Go to application menu table(sys_app_application) , find your application and add the module.